# Bottom of Screen of 4k Display is Black

Tags: uefi, screen, acer, 4k-monitor

I just bought an Acer Aspire VN7-591G-70CY (4k display version) and installed Ubuntu after disabling UEFI and using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it?lq=1) (nomodeset). It didn't work with UEFI enabled.

In the live session and with the installed OS the bottom of the screen (about as high as the trash icon in the launcher, I only can see its top) keeps always black. It's black already in grub.

I tried to figure out whether it has something to do with UEFI (the preinstalled Windows 8 **only** boots with UEFI) but I couldn't get Ubuntu to boot with UEFI. When selecting UEFI in the bios settings, Windows Boot Loader appears in the boot mediums (for whatever reason). I made sure to place the HDD above the Windows Boot loader but it goes straight to Windows and doesn't load grub. With an USB stick I can't get **Ubuntu to boot any further than to the Ubuntu logo with the dots under it.** I also can't manage to do the change of settings as explained by the thread linked to above because the part when I could change the settings is skipped.

I also tried to figure out whether this can be cured by installing additional graphics drivers but none helped and some prevented me from logging in via GUI (neither into my account nor into the guest account, logging in via a TTY, however, worked and that's how I removed the driver afterwards).

I don't care at all whether I can use Windows or not, I just want the black stripe to vanish.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14045/sorting-out-solved-for-good < thanks :)

Comment: What should I have done differently? This user was complaining that someone didn't state how they solved the problem. I first posted how I solved it and then wrote "(SOLVED)" in the title to tell others. I of course tried to accept my own answer as the solution but it didn't work. It said that I can do this in 2 days.

Comment: No. The point is to not write solved, we are not a forum, wait to accept the answer.

Comment: I wanted to prevent people from clicking on this question unnecessarily and just to find out that I already figured out a solution which works for me. But okay, I won't write "solved" into the title anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem and don't want to delete the question because I think this could be interesting for other people as well.

I simply changed

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

in `/etc/default/grub`, ran `sudo update-grub` rebooted and the problem was resolved. :)